# Paraview for Data Display Over Time

Tags: python, numpy, vtk, paraview

I am trying to use Paraview to display points as colored boxes that change scalar value over time. I have tried to write a programmable source and filter that adds box glyphs to data points and will change the scalar value of the data point based on the time point.

Specifically this script attempts to return an integer value for the current time point and then use this value to parse through a text file and choose the point data corresponding to that time point.

I can’t quite get it to work though and I have two big questions:

1. Within the Filter, how do I create glyph boxes for the data points?
2. How do I get the below script to work without getting "indices must be integers not float" error.

Many thanks,

Matt

## UPDATE

solved problem by adding:
    time = int(time)
after time = 0 in programmable filter

## Programmable Source Script

```
import vtk
import numpy as np

coordinate = np.array([[0,0,0]])

node_file = open(‘…/pointWeights.txt', 'r')
data = node_file.readlines()

timePoint = 0
pointWeight = float(data[timePoint])

node_file.close()

output.Points = coordinate

output.Allocate(1)

output.PointData.append(pointWeight, "Point Weight")
```

## Programmable Source RequestInformation

```
timeSteps = range(4)

outInfo = self.GetOutputInformation(0)

timeRange = [timeSteps[0], timeSteps[-1]]
outInfo.Set(vtk.vtkStreamingDemandDrivenPipeline.TIME_RANGE(), timeRange, 2)
outInfo.Set(vtk.vtkStreamingDemandDrivenPipeline.TIME_STEPS(), timeSteps, len(timeSteps))
```

## Programmable Filter Script

```
import vtk
import numpy as np

outInfo = self.GetOutputInformation(0)
if outInfo.Has(vtk.vtkStreamingDemandDrivenPipeline.UPDATE_TIME_STEP()):
  time = outInfo.Get(vtk.vtkStreamingDemandDrivenPipeline.UPDATE_TIME_STEP())
else:
  time = 0

coordinate = np.array([[0,0,0]])

node_file = open(‘…/pointWeights.txt', 'r')
data = node_file.readlines()

pointWeight = float(data[time])

node_file.close()

output.Points = coordinate

output.Allocate(1)

output.PointData.append(pointWeight, "Point Weight")
```

## pointWeights.txt

```
0
.33
.66
1
```

Comment: I don't understand what the programmable filter is for. The programmable source is already loading the value from pointWeights.txt, and that seems like the right place to do it. From there can't you just add a glyph filter that scales by the "Point Weight" field?

Comment: You are right, I am not sure why I thought I needed a filter to interact with Paraview's time feature. Thanks very much!